# Copying an XML structure only with relevant posts using ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have Python script that parses a number of XML files with the same structure, finds relevant elements and prints all tags and attibutes (and writes to file, but I would like to create some structured data instead).

This works perfectly fine, but I would like create a new XML file mirroring the *structure* of the original, but only with the elements matching the patterns I specified.

Here's the function that searches through the files:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import glob

filename = "media_code2_output.txt"

def find_mediacode2(inputfile, outputfile):
    #find parent node
    for parent in root.iter("musa"):
        #parent node attribute "dr-production" must be true (as string)
        if parent.attrib["dr-production"] == "true":
            #each child element must have media-code element be 2.
            for mediekode in parent.iter("media-code"):
                if mediekode.text  == "2":
                    #pint all fields
                    for field in parent.iter():
                        print(field.tag, field.attrib, field.text)
                        #write all fields to file
                        outputfile.write(str(field.tag) + " " + str(field.attrib) + " " + str(field.text) + "\n") 
                    #print spacer line 
                    outputfile.write("\n"+"-"*80+"\n")
                    print("\n"+"-"*80+"\n")


for inputfile in glob.glob('*/*.xml'):
    tree = ET.parse(inputfile)
    root = tree.getroot()

    with open(filename, "a+") as outputfile:
        find_mediacode2(root, outputfile)
```

Here's a sample of the data from the files:
https://pastebin.com/AHEcDv36

Ideally, I would like to represent the data in an Access database.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. New elements can be created using `Element` and `SubElement` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents). Have you tried that?

Comment: Otherwise I suggest using XSLT, which is very well suited to transformations from one XML structure to another.